# Does gdb support selective `auto-solib-add`?

Tags: gdb, debug-symbols

I am debugging a big command line program which will load many *.so libraries at startup.

If `auto-solib-add` is `on`, there would be too many symbols to load and `gdb` would just hang. Therefore, our best-practice is to turn off `auto-solib-add` in `.gdbinit` and manually load symbols of selected libraries via `sharedlibrary`.

There are some *.so libraries that we cannot run `sharedlibrary` right after the program starts, because these libraries have not been loaded yet. We need to execute a command, say `dosomething`, in the program to trigger the loading of these libraries. After that, these libraries will be visible in `gdb` for `sharedlibrary`.

This is working in most debugging scenarios, but there is a situation that I am having trouble with. One of the libraries that gets loaded through `dosomething` is called `libfoo.so` and its API `foo()` is executed during `dosomething`. How do I break in `foo()` during `dosomething`? In other words, with the following mental image of the program stages, how do I pause `gdb` after `stage j` and before `stage k` so I can load symbols before `foo()` gets executed?

```
* ...
* Stage i: In the main program interface, the command `dosomething` is issued. This will trigger the loading of some dynamic linked libraries, including `libfoo.so`.
* ...
* Stage j: `libfoo.so` is loaded.
* ...
* Stage k: `foo()` is executed.
* ...
* Stage l: The command `dosomething` finishes and returns the control to the user in the main program.
* ...
```

Note: For some technical reasons, I also cannot turn on `auto-solib-add` after the main program starts and before I run `dosomething` to trigger the loading of those libraries. Otherwise, I know this could be a workaround rather than trying to manually pause at a sweet spot between `stage j` and `stage k`.

Comment: Why don't you know when `foo.so` is loaded? Either it is loaded at program start, or by a `dlopen()` call.

Comment: @ssbssa, I think breaking in `dlopen` would work. I wasn't aware of this. Would you post it as an answer so I can mark?

Comment: "There is a function, say foo(), in library foo.so. foo.so is loaded when the first call to foo() is made." -- that isn't _at all_ how dynamic loader works. Why don't you describe your _actual_ problem?

Comment: @EmployedRussian. To be honest, I am not quite familiar with how exactly dynamic loader works, but the description is what I infer from my observation. Please point out if there is a more accurate way of describing the call-load interaction. Also feel free to correct as needed regarding my mental image. In terms of the function name and library name, I cannot use the real names for confidential reasons.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got my head around by studying up this article:

[developer.ibm.com/tutorials/l-dynamic-libraries](https://developer.ibm.com/tutorials/l-dynamic-libraries)

If we number the three library usage scenarios as:

1. Static library.
2. Shared library dynamic linking.
3. Shared library dynamic loading.

The loading of `libfoo.so` belongs to 3), with which the `dlopen` library is used to trigger loading from the application (but still through system's dynamic linker that handles 2) as well).

Running the following in `gdb` after the program starts would allow us to stop for every dynamic loading.

```
sharedlibrary libdl.so
b dlopen
```

The point I was looking for between `stage j` and `stage k` can be right after `dlopen` returns to its caller for `libfoo.so`.

As pointed out by @EmployedRussian, this can also be done through the following gdb feature:

```
set stop-on-solib-events 1
```

Comment: Using `set stop-on-solib-events 1` would also solve this.

Comment: Link is dead. Is https://developer.ibm.com/tutorials/l-dynamic-libraries/ now the correct one?